# Installing USB dialup modem on debian

Tags: linux, debian, usb

I want to install a USB dial-up modem on my Debian server and call a phone number with my modem, but i didn't find any useful document.
please help me to install my modem on my server or provide me a useful link or document

```
#uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1 (2019-04-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
#lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 047e:2892 Agere Systems, Inc. (Lucent) Systems Soft Modem
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
#dmesg
...
[9926268.631149] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[9926269.203924] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=047e, idProduct=2892
[9926269.203930] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[9926269.203933] usb 2-1: Product: Agere USB2.0 V.92 SoftModem
[9926269.203935] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Agere Systems
```

```
# ls -l /dev
crw------- 1 root root     10, 175 Jun 15 09:50 agpgart
crw------- 1 root root     10, 235 Jun 15 09:50 autofs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root         180 Jun 15 09:50 block
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          80 Jun 15 09:50 bsg
crw------- 1 root root     10, 234 Jun 15 09:50 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root          60 Jun 15 09:50 bus
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 Jun 15 09:50 cdrom -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 Jun 15 09:50 cdrw -> sr0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        2660 Oct  8 07:04 char
crw------- 1 root root      5,   1 Jun 15 09:50 console
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          11 Jun 15 09:50 core -> /proc/kcore
crw------- 1 root root     10,  62 Jun 15 09:50 cpu_dma_latency
crw------- 1 root root     10, 203 Jun 15 09:50 cuse
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root         120 Jun 15 09:50 disk
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root         100 Jun 15 09:50 dri
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           3 Jun 15 09:50 dvd -> sr0
crw-rw---- 1 root video    29,   0 Jun 15 09:50 fb0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          13 Jun 15 09:50 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   7 Jun 15 09:50 full
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root     10, 229 Jun 15 09:50 fuse
crw------- 1 root root    249,   0 Jun 15 09:50 hidraw0
crw------- 1 root root     10, 228 Jun 15 09:50 hpet
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           0 Jun 15 09:50 hugepages
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          25 Jun 15 09:50 initctl -> /run/systemd/initctl/fifo
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root         280 Jun 15 09:50 input
crw-r--r-- 1 root root      1,  11 Jun 15 09:50 kmsg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          28 Jun 15 09:50 log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
crw-rw---- 1 root disk     10, 237 Jun 15 09:50 loop-control
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          60 Jun 15 09:50 mapper
crw------- 1 root root     10, 227 Jun 15 09:50 mcelog
crw-r----- 1 root kmem      1,   1 Jun 15 09:50 mem
crw------- 1 root root     10,  59 Jun 15 09:50 memory_bandwidth
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root          40 Jun 15 09:50 mqueue
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          60 Jun 15 09:50 net
crw------- 1 root root     10,  61 Jun 15 09:50 network_latency
crw------- 1 root root     10,  60 Jun 15 09:50 network_throughput
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   3 Jun 15 09:50 null
crw-r----- 1 root kmem      1,   4 Jun 15 09:50 port
crw------- 1 root root    108,   0 Jun 15 09:50 ppp
crw------- 1 root root     10,   1 Jun 15 09:50 psaux
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty       5,   2 Oct  8  2019 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root           0 Jun 15 09:50 pts
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   8 Jun 15 09:50 random
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           4 Jun 15 09:50 rtc -> rtc0
crw------- 1 root root    252,   0 Jun 15 09:50 rtc0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   0 Jun 15 09:50 sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   1 Jun 15 09:50 sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   2 Jun 15 09:50 sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   5 Jun 15 09:50 sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   6 Jun 15 09:50 sda6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   7 Jun 15 09:50 sda7
crw-rw---- 1 root disk     21,   0 Jun 15 09:50 sg0
crw-rw---- 1 root cdrom    21,   1 Jun 15 09:50 sg1
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root          40 Jun 15 09:50 shm
crw------- 1 root root     10, 231 Jun 15 09:50 snapshot
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          80 Jun 15 09:50 snd
brw-rw---- 1 root cdrom    11,   0 Jun 15 09:50 sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          15 Jun 15 09:50 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          15 Jun 15 09:50 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          15 Jun 15 09:50 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty       5,   0 Oct  8 06:52 tty
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   0 Jun 15 09:50 tty0
crw------- 1 root tty       4,   1 Jun 16 06:41 tty1
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  10 Jun 15 09:50 tty10
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  11 Jun 15 09:50 tty11
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  12 Jun 15 09:50 tty12
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  13 Jun 15 09:50 tty13
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  14 Jun 15 09:50 tty14
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  15 Jun 15 09:50 tty15
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  16 Jun 15 09:50 tty16
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  17 Jun 15 09:50 tty17
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  18 Jun 15 09:50 tty18
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  19 Jun 15 09:50 tty19
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   2 Jun 15 09:50 tty2
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  20 Jun 15 09:50 tty20
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  21 Jun 15 09:50 tty21
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  22 Jun 15 09:50 tty22
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  23 Jun 15 09:50 tty23
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  24 Jun 15 09:50 tty24
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  25 Jun 15 09:50 tty25
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  26 Jun 15 09:50 tty26
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  27 Jun 15 09:50 tty27
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  28 Jun 15 09:50 tty28
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  29 Jun 15 09:50 tty29
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   3 Jun 15 09:50 tty3
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  30 Jun 15 09:50 tty30
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  31 Jun 15 09:50 tty31
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  32 Jun 15 09:50 tty32
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  33 Jun 15 09:50 tty33
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  34 Jun 15 09:50 tty34
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  35 Jun 15 09:50 tty35
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  36 Jun 15 09:50 tty36
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  37 Jun 15 09:50 tty37
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  38 Jun 15 09:50 tty38
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  39 Jun 15 09:50 tty39
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   4 Jun 15 09:50 tty4
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  40 Jun 15 09:50 tty40
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  41 Jun 15 09:50 tty41
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  42 Jun 15 09:50 tty42
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  43 Jun 15 09:50 tty43
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  44 Jun 15 09:50 tty44
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  45 Jun 15 09:50 tty45
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  46 Jun 15 09:50 tty46
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  47 Jun 15 09:50 tty47
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  48 Jun 15 09:50 tty48
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  49 Jun 15 09:50 tty49
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   5 Jun 15 09:50 tty5
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  50 Jun 15 09:50 tty50
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  51 Jun 15 09:50 tty51
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  52 Jun 15 09:50 tty52
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  53 Jun 15 09:50 tty53
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  54 Jun 15 09:50 tty54
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  55 Jun 15 09:50 tty55
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  56 Jun 15 09:50 tty56
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  57 Jun 15 09:50 tty57
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  58 Jun 15 09:50 tty58
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  59 Jun 15 09:50 tty59
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   6 Jun 15 09:50 tty6
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  60 Jun 15 09:50 tty60
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  61 Jun 15 09:50 tty61
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  62 Jun 15 09:50 tty62
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  63 Jun 15 09:50 tty63
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   7 Jun 15 09:50 tty7
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   8 Jun 15 09:50 tty8
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,   9 Jun 15 09:50 tty9
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4,  64 Jun 15 09:50 ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4,  65 Jun 15 09:50 ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4,  66 Jun 15 09:50 ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4,  67 Jun 15 09:50 ttyS3
crw------- 1 root root     10, 239 Jun 15 09:50 uhid
crw------- 1 root root     10, 223 Jun 15 09:50 uinput
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   9 Jun 15 09:50 urandom
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7,   0 Jun 15 09:50 vcs
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7,   1 Jun 15 09:50 vcs1
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7,   2 Jun 15 09:50 vcs2
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7,   3 Jun 15 09:50 vcs3
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7,   4 Jun 15 09:50 vcs4
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7,   5 Jun 15 09:50 vcs5
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7,   6 Jun 15 09:50 vcs6
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 128 Jun 15 09:50 vcsa
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 129 Jun 15 09:50 vcsa1
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 130 Jun 15 09:50 vcsa2
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 131 Jun 15 09:50 vcsa3
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 132 Jun 15 09:50 vcsa4
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 133 Jun 15 09:50 vcsa5
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 134 Jun 15 09:50 vcsa6
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          60 Jun 15 09:50 vfio
crw------- 1 root root     10,  63 Jun 15 09:50 vga_arbiter
crw------- 1 root root     10, 137 Jun 15 09:50 vhci
crw------- 1 root root     10, 238 Jun 15 09:50 vhost-net
crw------- 1 root root     10,  58 Jun 15 09:50 vmci
crw------- 1 root root     10,  57 Jun 15 09:50 vsock
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root      1,   5 Jun 15 09:50 zero
```

I can't find any change in my `/dev` by removing the USB device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have what is known as a Soft Modem (sometimes called WinModems).

These devices do not present them selves as a normal modem would (as a serial device that accepts AT commands) but as a custom USB device that require a special driver. These drivers were traditionally only ever made available for Windows and as such were unusable by any other Operating System.

A quick search threw up this Ubuntu [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/Lucent/Agere) that may help as it talks about a custom kernel module that may work with your device. But the page references 2.6.x kernels so may be VERY out of date.

You can also have a poke around on [linmodems.org](http://www.linmodems.org/) which used to house the community work to try and make these devices useful on Linux.

p.s. the shortest easiest answer here, may be to go out and buy REAL modem